# Issue: Action redirect do not include parameter as complex objects in Struts2?

Tags: redirect, struts2, action

I have tried an example in which i have inserted a user using insert method of UserAction class.

On insert I have redirected the success to loadAdd method of UserAction.

During redirect I have passed the parameter as

${user}

In struts 2.0.14 this gives an ognl exception.

whereas when I pass

${user.id}

it works.

My observation says this is a bug in struts or ognl that it does parse composite objects while it parses simple data types.

Any work-around please suggest.

Or

Is there any way by which I can forward the complete action context or value stack in the redirected action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug.

Struts2 uses a type conversion system to convert between Strings (native HTTP) and other objects. It has default type converters for all of the standard primitives, boxed primitives, collections, maps, etc. If you want to allow Struts2 to automatically convert between a string and your User class, you need to create a type converter for it. Otherwise, you can use ${user.id}, which is a primitive or boxed primitive.

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/type-conversion.html

Also, the ValueStack is per-request, so when you redirect and create a new request, the previous requests ValueStack is no longer available.

Comment: Its not a bug exactly I know, but instead of stopping the execution, default user.id could have been used by struts. What user gets is a long exception stack trace if not handled and program stops. So a concern for struts2 community. Thanks for referring me to user defined type-conversion but not sure I will really be able to dump the complete user object including its several linked objects & sets directly using this. User object has almost 12 basic types, 10 complex objects which again have further objects & 4 sets.

Comment: Type conversion isn't a replacement for user.name, user.email, etc. It's just to set what user is. You seem to want user.id and user to be synonymous. Perhaps you can clarify what it is you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I am looking for passing the complete user object along with its nested objects & sets when action is redirected. As this data is not posted but Get is used so, I have to just pass the id. So what I am looking forward is Post some data during action redirect or forward the complete value stack to the redirected action. Any workarounds for it?